# Change watchkit controller title font size

Tags: ios, watchkit

Very basic question. How to change the font size of the title of a Watchkit Controller? 
I have thoroughly searched Apple's documentation and other stackoverflow question and couldn't find the answer to this specific topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer? You can't. None of the status bar elements have been opened to developers.

Comment: that means that I cannot even change the System font and use the San Francisco font instead? I am asking specifically about the title of the controller. Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to be more specific. The title for the interface refers to the label in the status bar. Do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean exactly the label in the status bar.